# Factory Method or Some Other Pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, factory

I have a Task entity that needs to be Resolved based on the type of Task it is. I would encapsulate the logic for a specific type of Task in a class, but what is the generally accepted way to match the type with the class that implements the Resolving logic?

My first impulse is to do a Factory, like:

```
TaskResolverFactory.GetForType(TaskType) // returns IsATaskResolver, which has a Resolve method
```

Probably inside the Factory, a Case statement or something.

Another thought is to use something like `StructureMap`, but I think that is overkill for this situation - do you agree?

What other methods am I missing, and what is the generally accepted method for replacing a big Case/Switch statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider something like this:

```
public class TaskResolverAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type ResolverType { get; private set; }

    public TaskResolverAttribute(Type resolverType)
    {
        if (!typeof(ITaskResolver).IsAssignableFrom(resolverType))
            throw new ArgumentException("resolverType must implement ITaskResolver");

        ResolverType = resolverType;
    }
}

public class MyTaskResolver : ITaskResolver
{
}

[TaskResolver(typeof(MyTaskResolver))]
public class MyTask
{
}

public static class TaskResolverFactory
{
    public static ITaskResolver GetForType(Type taskType)
    {
        var attribute =
            Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(taskType, typeof(TaskResolverAttribute)) as TaskResolverAttribute;
        if (attribute == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Task does not have an associated TaskResolver");

        return (ITaskResolver)Activator.CreateInstance(attribute.ResolverType);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow - I haven't done any Attribute coding, that looks too incredibly easy. Thanks for that!

Comment: @grefly, it's well-suited for use cases like this.  MS used the same pattern for associating TypeConverter classes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverterattribute.aspx

Comment: I think that is exactly what I was looking for, without knowing what I was looking for. Thanks, re-assigned Answer to you, with apologies to @Oded.

Answer (score 2):

You are right - a `Factory` is the classic pattern for this issue.

If this is the only place you need to do such resolution (and the logic is simple), I agree - `StructureMap` *is* overkill.

Comment: Sorry to switch on you - the Attributes answer seems perfect.

Comment: @grefly - no problem. You should go with the best answer, as you see it. However, perhaps in the future, wait for a day or two before accepting an answer to see what comes up.

Comment: Yep, will do - jumped the gun.

Answer (score 0):

A factory is the way to go.

As for the big switch statement, your other options include:

- Configuration/lookup file
- A database
- Reflection

I think the reflection route is the easiest to maintain but the complexity arises when you don't already have the type (assuming your "type" is a `Type`).

Since you already have the type, the rest is real easy:

```
public static Task GetByType(Type taskType)
{
    return Activator.CreateInstance(taskType) as Task;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for going into a little more detail. Sorry I can't mark both as Answer.

Comment: My implementation (which I think will help describe the issue) would be like this:

GetByType(TaskType)
  if( TaskType Is AddUserTask )
    return AddUserTaskResolution
  
  if( TaskType Is RemoveUserTask )
    return RemoveUserTaskResolution

etc.